# count images in pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, junit, pdfbox

I have a need to extract the text from a pdf to validate some content and count the number of images in the pdf document using java. I can get the text content no problems using the getText function below but can't find a way to get a count on just the image objects. I have been able to get a count of all objects using the code below but can't find any doco on how to only count the images. Any ideas would be very appreciated. Thanks

```
static String getText(File pdfFile) throws IOException {
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
    return new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
 }

static void countImages(File pdfFile) throws IOException{

   PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
   List myObjects = doc.getDocument().getObjects();
   System.out.println("Count: " + myObjects.size());
   doc.close();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution could look like this:

```
static void countImages(File pdfFile) throws IOException{
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
    PDResources res = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().getResources();

    int numImg = 0;
    for (PDXObject xobject : res.getXObjects().values()) {
        if (xobject instanceof PDXObjectImage) {
            numImg++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Count: " + numImg);

    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: this ignores quite a number of places images can be. Furthermore, there is no guarantee an image in a page's resources is actually used I  the page.

Comment: @mkl Interesting but vague. Why don't you share your pearls of wisdom and post a better answer? I used my approach for just two test cases which had to ensure that a specific pdf either contained an image or not. Since it worked reliably, I did not dive any deeper into that topic.

Comment: @Würgspaß have a look at the ExtractImages source code in the source code download or here https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractImages.java?view=markup

Comment: @Würgspaß "Interesting but vague" - **A** your code only looks into page resources. Thus, it does not find the images in form XObject resources or pattern resources. Furthermore, it also ignores inline images (which are inlined in a content stream). **B** only because an image resource exists in a page's resources, it is not necessarily used on that page. There are PDFs in which all pages share a single resource dictionary which contains all images directly used on those pages. Your code counts each image as often as there are pages while it might be used on only one page.

Comment: @Würgspaß *"Why don't you share your pearls of wisdom and post a better answer?"* - Because it is not clear what "counting images" really means. If the same image resource is used multiple times, either on the same page or on different pages, shall that count as 1, as number of pages on which that image is used or as number of actually uses. What if different sections of a single image are used? What if an image is outside the crop box? Or hidden under some other content? What about images in annotations? In case of optional content, shall all images count or only in visible groups? Etc etc...

Comment: That is probably why he included "*quick and dirty solution*". It may work for some. But it would also be good to include for which instances the approach works and for which not.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(""));

    int numImages = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
    {
        PDPage page = document.getPage(i);

        CountImages countImages = new CountImages(page);
        countImages.processPage(page);

        numImages += countImages.numImages;
    }

    System.out.println(numImages);
}

static class CountImages extends PDFGraphicsStreamEngine {
    public int numImages = 0;
    private final Set<COSStream> duplicates = new HashSet<>();

    protected CountImages(PDPage page) throws IOException
    {
        super(page);
    }

    @Override
    public void appendRectangle(Point2D pd, Point2D pd1, Point2D pd2, Point2D pd3) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void drawImage(PDImage pdImage) throws IOException {
        if (pdImage instanceof PDImageXObject) {
            PDImageXObject xobject = (PDImageXObject)pdImage;

            if (duplicates.contains(xobject.getCOSObject()) == false) {
                numImages++;
                duplicates.add(xobject.getCOSObject());
            }
        } else {
            numImages++; //means its an inline image
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clip(int i) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void moveTo(float f, float f1) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void lineTo(float f, float f1) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void curveTo(float f, float f1, float f2, float f3, float f4, float f5) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public Point2D getCurrentPoint() throws IOException {
        return new Point2D.Float(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void closePath() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void endPath() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void strokePath() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void fillPath(int i) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void fillAndStrokePath(int i) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void shadingFill(COSName cosn) throws IOException {
    }
}
```